# Reading file from assets folder with expo go

Tags: expo

Trying to read a file from assets folder with react native **expo go**

```js
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
...
  const getFiles = async () => {
    const [{ localUri }] = await Asset.loadAsync(
      require("./assets/gpx/test.txt")
    );
    console.log("localUri", localUri);
    console.log(
      "readAsStringAsync",
      FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(localUri)
    );
...
```

this code returns the correct localUri

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FExpoGeolocation-c1ebf94c-e515-4d59-bcb8-5d1f1ce948bf/ExponentAsset-5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592.txt
```

but the function `readAsStringAsync()` always returns

```
{"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}
```

how can I read txt (or csv or something else) file from assets directory with react native **expo go**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're so close, you're just missing an await.

console.log(
"readAsStringAsync",
**await** FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(localUri)
);